# iPod Touch not recognized by iTunes/iExplorer on one PC but is recognized on other

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod-touch

I have restarted PC, restarted iPod service, etc. It is recognized by PC as a device, but not on iTunes/iExplorer.

Here is an image:

[image]

I need to manage files. My iPod is jailbroken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this problem once too. Make sure you've got the all the services that itunes installs running like Bonjore service, iPod service ect. Try the solutions on [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1363) if you cant sort it out.

Comment: No luck, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I actually forgot to read the link that he gave me.